# 415 Unsupported Media Type Error on JSON HttpPost

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, http-post, fiddler

I have controller with the following code using ASP.NET Core -

```
namespace WebApplication.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class TodoController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public List<Testing> Create([FromBody] List<Testing> item)
        {
            return item;
        }
    }
}
```

When I try and do an HTTP post as follows using fiddler  -

```
POST - http://localhost:30001/api/todo
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Host: localhost:30001
Content-Length: 117

[{"Name":"Item1","LastName":"Test1"}, {"Name":"Item2","LastName":"Test2"}, {"Name":"Item3","LastName":"Test3"}]
```

I end up with a 415 Unsupported Media Type exception. If I remove the [FromBody] attribute from the parameters in the POST request are null. How do I fix the binding?

Comment: Do you have any middleware or settings changing default content type? I've just tried your code snippet with `[FromBody]` and it works for me.

Comment: same issue. did you ever resolve this?